# Horizontal list: fill empty spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

## Introduction

I'm currently redesigning my personal album page, mostly because I am using a bunch of outdated javascript libarries. Anyways, here is what an album in my gallery looks like:

[image: image grid]

To lay out the images, I have implemented the following algorithm in javascript.

1. Note, that all images share a certain fixed width. So we can determine the number of available columns `C` for images by dividing the width of the viewport by the width of the images.
2. Allocate an Array containing the total height of the images in every colum. This array has length `C` and is initialized with `0`
3. For each image to assign:

   1. Find the column with the minimum assigned height
   2. Add the image to this column with absolute positioning
   3. Increase the column-height in `C` by the height of the image.

## The Question

Now that I am rebuilding the site, I am wondering: **Is there a way to achieve the above layout without js using floats or the like?**

Comment: This can be done with masonry layout, but in order to have them horizontally aligned at the bottom, you need to plan in advance. As far as I can see you only have 2 different heights and that's good. In order to achieve this you need to combine those div's in columns in the way so they all match up at the end. But keep in mind that each additional image can and will break the layout...This can be avoided by adding the right number of images with the right height to keep that horizontal alignment.

Comment: There will not exact css matching to your algorithm but please take care to see https://codepen.io/AdamBlum/pen/fwrnE, it will something similar to what you are seeking.